# Making a json file with an array of values to a key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have many checkboxes in the html page. I have to send the json data to the server with an array of id's of all the checkboxes that are checked and also the label for these checkboxes.
I was thinking of using jquery with .each() function to check if a checkbox is checked and if it checked add it to the array.
The json file i am looking for is like this

```
{"checkbox id" : [1, 2, 3], "checkbox label" : ["check1", "check2", "check3"]}
```

Comment: Can you provide some checkboxes to play with ? following the result you want to achieve

Comment: actually i am adding checkboxes with there id's dynamically with angular js like this  '                                                                                <li ng-repeat="missioncontent in  mission.missionContent"class="unorderedlist">
                                <div style="">
                                    <input id="{{missioncontent.id}}"  type="checkbox"/>
                                    <label>{{missioncontent.info}}</label>
                                </div>
                            </li>'

Comment: So you should be able to give the output.

Comment: "missioncontent.id" is the id of the checkbox and "missioncontent.info" is the label of the checkbox

Comment: i am struggling with making the json file of the above format, i have the ids and labels already in the array

Comment: So you want to push in an array the ids and than in other array push labels.than assign this arrays to objects

Comment: yes, thats what i  want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the json structure, you can do the following:

```
var ids = [];
var labels = [];

$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var current_id = $(this).attr('id');
        ids.push(current_id);

        var current_label = $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']").text();
        labels.push(current_label);
    }
});

var checkboxes = {
    "checkbox_id": ids,
    "checkbox_label": labels
};

var s_checkboxes = JSON.stringify(checkboxes);
```

Notice that **you can't create a json file in the browser**. You will have to do that in the server-side, once the data has been sent.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the jquery :checked selector to get all the checkboxes that are checked..

var checkedCheckBoxes = $( "input:checked" )

[jQuery checked selector](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Comment: and how to make the json file, that is the main thing i am struggling with

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this HTML:

```
 <label for="checkBox">Label</label>
 <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox" />
```

I would suggest this form of json:

```
var arr = [];
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var id = that.attr('id');
    var label = $('label[for="' + id + '"]').text();
    var obj = {
       id: id,
       label: label
    }
    arr.push(obj);
});
```

And you would come up with this:

```
arr = [{id:"1",label:"labelOne"},{ ... }];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to format your JSON, I'd put all the information on the checked boxes inside an array looking like this:

```
{
  "checked_boxes" :
    [{"id": "1", "label": "checkbox1"},
     {"id": "2", "label": "checkbox2"},
     {"id": "3", "label": "checkbox3"]
}
```